# Where can I find Argentina Admin 3-4 & City .shp?

Tags: data-request, argentina

I am able to find Admin 0-2 Boundary data from HDX, however, I cannot find a data source for admin3-4 polygon boundaries for Argentina.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you had seen this ?

http://www.diva-gis.org/

http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/first.shtml

https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these sites break it down further than Admin2

Comment: Ok Perhaps if you live there in Argentina maybe contact the university there such as Geography or Urban Planning department ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I am on a rock in the middle of the Pacific, so stopping by is a bit out of the question :)

But in all seriousness, I can't believe this information is not out there.

Comment: @A.S.  -- Keep trying and google and I suggest you to screenshot of it  what you are looking for so us it can help you out what to look for.  I am at the edge of the Rocky Mountain Front range here in the Western US.

Comment: Pueblo , CO here

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the Openstreetmap.org admin boundaries which you can easily download from this nice web site: https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

It is ordered by country, hence easy to navigate. Download is provided in vector formats.

[image]